# Get the Cookies from external browser(Installed browser app) or system webview and assign to webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, azure-ad-msal

Problem - I tried to log in with MSAL lib and then open the webview in the app. I think MSAL lib using system webview and return back me with a valid token. Now I'm trying to load portal URL in webview which is asking credentials again(Not expected scenario)

Solution - I have to get the cookies from system webview(Or external browser mean installed browser app) and assign same cookies to webview.

Q1. Is it possible to get the cookies or not? If yes, please provide the example.

Q2. Any other alternate solution?

Comment: no, it is not possible. It would be an enormous security issue if it was possible

Comment: Finally, I got the solution - We have to use Chrome custom tabs (Android support lib). Chrome custome comes with two main features those are following
1. Occurs in a secure context (the system browser) where the host app cannot inspect contents.
2. Has a shared cookie state, ensuring the user has to sign in only once.
[Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/work/guide#sso)